# Python Pandas iterrows method

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm "pseudo" creating a .bib file by reading a csv file and then following this [structure](http://pastebin.com/VmpFSMEA) writing down every thing including newline characters. It's a tedious process but it's a raw form on converting csv to .bib in python.

I'm using Pandas to read csv and write row by row, (and since it has special characters I'm using latin1 encoder) but I'm getting a huge problem: it only reads the first row. From the official [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) I'm using their method on reading row by row, which only gives me the first row (example 1):

```
 row = next(df.iterrows())[1]
```

But if I remove the next() and [1] it gives me the content of every column concentrated in one field (example 2).

**Why is this happenning? Why using the method in the docs does not iterate through all rows nicely? How would be the solution for example 1 but for all rows?**

My code:

```
import csv
import pandas
import bibtexparser
import codecs

colnames = ['AUTORES', 'TITULO', 'OUTROS', 'DATA','NOMEREVISTA','LOCAL','VOL','NUM','PAG','PAG2','ISBN','ISSN','ISSN2','ERC','IF','DOI','CODEN','WOS','SCOPUS','URL','CODIGO BIBLIOGRAFICO','INDEXAÇÕES',
        'EXTRAINFO','TESTE']
data = pandas.read_csv('test1.csv', names=colnames, delimiter =r";", encoding='latin1')#, nrows=1

df = pandas.DataFrame(data=data)

with codecs.open('test1.txt', 'w', encoding='latin1') as fh:
    fh.write('@Book{Arp, ')
    fh.write('\n')

rl = data.iterrows()

for i in rl:
    ix = str(i)
    fh.write('  Title                    = {')
    fh.write(ix)
    fh.write('}')
    fh.write('\n')
```

PS: I'm new to python and programming, I know this code has flaws and it's not the most effective way to convert csv to bib.

Comment: Example 1:http://pastebin.com/HaZUgKpe

Example 2:http://pastebin.com/cScWse2G

Comment: `iterrows` gives you a `(index, row)` tuple on each iteration. The best way to use it is generally to do `for ix, row in data.iterrows():`, not using `next()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example `row = next(df.iterrows())[1]` intentionally only returns the first row.

`df.iterrows()` returns a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) over *tuples* describing the rows. The tuple's first entry contains the row index and the second entry is a pandas series with your data of the row.

Hence, `next(df.iterrows())` returns the next entry of the generator. If `next` has not been called before, this is the very first *tuple*.
Accordingly, `next(df.iterrows())[1]` returns the first row (i.e. the second tuple entry) as a pandas series.

What you are looking for is probably something like this:

```
for row_index, row in df.iterrows():
   convert_to_bib(row)
```

Secondly, all your writing to your file handle `fh` must happen within the block `with codecs.open('test1.txt', 'w', encoding='latin1') as fh:`
because at the end of the block the file handle will be closed.

For example:

```
with codecs.open('test1.txt', 'w', encoding='latin1') as fh:
    # iterate through all rows
    for row_index, row in df.iterrows():
       # iterate through all elements in the row
       for colname in df.columns:
           row_element = row[colname]
           fh.write('%s = {%s},\n' % (colname, str(row_element)))
```

Still I am not sure if the names of the columns exactly match the bibtex fields you have in mind. Probably you have to convert these first. But I hope you get the principle behind the iterations :-)